# How to create Aspect for mapper classes generated by mybatis framework?

Tags: java, spring, aop, mybatis

I want to create aspect for profiling db calls using mybatis with this pointcut

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * org.example.mybatisgenerated.*Mapper+.*(..) )")
public void anyGeneratedMapperMethod(){}
```

Problem is that mappers are interfaces and there are no concrete classes, like this.

```
public interface SampleMapper {

  int deleteByPrimaryKey(String sampleGuid);

  int insert(Sample record);
}
```

Implementation of mapper(actual sql scripts) are in xml files. Concrete classes are created as proxies. Is it possible to somehow advice all methods of mappers?

Aspectj load-time weaving is used.
May be this is possible with some another kind of weaving.
I do not want to wrap all mappers with concrete implementation, it will be a lot of useless classes.

Comment: There is an interceptor build-in feature in MyBatis ( [link](http://www.mybatis.org/core/configuration.html#plugins) ). Maybe you can use it ?

Answer (score 2):

There is an [interceptor build-in feature in MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/core/configuration.html#plugins). Maybe you can use it ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

The only problem with this is, I cannot register an interceptor for an entire mapper in one go. Is there a workaround for registering an interceptor for a mapper interface, rather than a single method?